# Unexpected mutation of (task) prop in vuejs (todolist list app )

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, vuex, store

I have store which contains state, mutation, getters etc. State contains list of tasks as given below.

```
const state = {
   tasks:[{
     title: "Wake up",
     completed: false
   },
   {
     title: "Item 2",
     completed: false
   },
  ]
}
```

`Todo.vue`

```
<template>
   <Task v-for="(task,key) in tasks" :id="key" :task="task" :key="key" />
</template>
<script>
import { defineComponent } from 'vue';
import Task from '../components/Task.vue'
import {mapGetters} from 'vuex'

export default defineComponent({
  name: 'PageIndex',
  components:{
    Task
  },
  computed:{
    ...mapGetters('task', ['tasks']) //fetched tasks from task module
  },
})
</script>
```

`Task.vue`

```
<template>
    <q-item  
        clickable 
        :class="!task.completed ? 'bg-orange-1' : 'bg-green-1'"
        v-ripple>
        <q-item-section side top>
          <q-checkbox v-model="task.completed" />  /////////////// problem is in this line
        </q-item-section>

        <q-item-section>
          <q-item-label :class="{'text-strikethrough' : 
          task.completed}">{{task.name}}</q-item-label>
        </q-item-section>
      </q-item>
</template>

<script>
    import {mapActions} from 'vuex'
    export default {
        props: ["task"],
    }
</script>
```

In above code, in Task.vue

```
<q-checkbox v-model="task.completed" />
```

Problem is in this line. If I remove `v-model="task.completed"`, from above given code, then everything works fine otherwise it throws error saying `Unexpected mutation of "task" prop`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're trying to mutate a prop and corresponding vuex state outside the mutation. Passing a value to the `v-model` directive will create a two-way data binding. Your `task` prop references an object in your state and when `q-checkbox` changes the value of `task.completed` the object is updated in your state directly. Instead you should create a mutation that will update your tasks:

```js
export const mutations = {
  updateTask(state, payload){
    const task = state.tasks.find(t => t.id === payload.id);

    if(task) Object.assign(task, payload)
  }
}
```

And then you can use this mutation in your template

```html
<q-checkbox :value="task.completed" @input="updateTask({id: task.id, completed: !task.completed})" />
```

Also note that actual prop and event name for `q-checkbox` component might be different, depending on your implementation

Comment: while syncing state I faced another error. Could you figure out what the issue is? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69478690/sync-modifier-on-v-bind-directive-is-deprecated-use-v-modelpropname-inst